# Accessing structure in C - functions

Tags: c, struct, structure

I am trying to play around with structures in C and I am stuck at this point. Here's my code:

```
 #include <stdio.h>

 void Test(void);
 void updateIt(struct Item* ptr);

 struct Item 
 {
     double value;
     int unitno;
     int isTa;
     int quant;
     int minQuant;
     char name[21];
 };

 int main(void)
 {
     Test();   // here I am gonna call updateit() function and print
 }

 void Test(void) {
     struct Item I = { 100.10,100,10,110,10,"NAME!" };
     updateIt(&I);
 } 

 void updateIt(struct Item* ptr){
     struct Item I[0] = 200 // This doesn't work — but why?
 }
```

How do I update values of `Item I = { 100.10,100,10,110,10,"NAME!" }` to `{ 200.20,200,20,220,20,"NAME2!"}` by accessing values inside the `updateIt` function?

Comment: Note that with C99 compound literals, you could write: `*ptr = (struct Item){ 200.20, 200, 20, 220, 20, "NAME2!"};` to assign a new value to the structure pointed at by the argument to the `updateIt()` function.

Answer (score 3):

In the code snippet:

```
void updateIt(struct Item* ptr){
 struct Item I[0] = 200 // This doesn't work — but why?
 }
```

There is no variable `I` in this scope.

Since you passed the address of the structure through `updateIt(&I);` in the above function you will have to use the pointer to it.

The pointer variable `ptr` in the arguments of the function has the address of the structure, which can be used to update the values as :

```
ptr->structureMember
```

where structureMember is any member of the structure.

Answer (score 1):

`updateIt(struct Item* ptr)` accepts pointer `ptr` of type item; to access fields of structure Item using a pointer, one should use `->` operator like below:

```
void updateIt(struct Item* ptr){
    ptr->value    = 200.20;
    ptr->unitno   = 200;
    ptr->isTa     = 20;
    ptr->quant    = 220;
    ptr->minQuant = 20;
    strcpy(ptr->name, "NAME2"); 
}
```

Comment: how do I get rid of compiler warnings?

Comment: warning: implicit declaration of function ‘strcpy’

Comment: include string.h header file at the start of your code file.

Answer (score 0):

You must use the ptr value like

ptr->unitno = 200 and so for every member of the struct

Comment: Thanks :) but upon doing strcpy I get warnings from compler " warning: implicit declaration of function ‘strcpy"

Comment: you need to include <string.h>

Comment: @John: when you get a warning about `strcpy()` — or almost any of the `str*` functions — the default fix is to `#include <string.h>`.  You will, in time, learn which standard functions are declared in which header.  The 'mighty trio' are `<stdio.h>`, `<stdlib.h>`, `<string.h>` — an awful lot of code can be written with just those three headers.